# Process each line in a buffer

Tags: string, mono, textview, buffer

I am very new to c#.  I am using Mono.  I want to loop through each line in a TextView object and do my own processing to each line.  I have narrowed it down to the Buffer property that contains a Text property but this property contains the whole text.  How do I break it down into separate lines/strings?

```
    string Line;
    for (int i = 0;i < txtvMain.Buffer.LineCount; i++)
    {
        Line = txtvMain.Buffer.?;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

(Untested) simple solution (perhaps not the most efficient):

```
string[] lines = txtvMain.Buffer.Text.split('\n');
```